# Parse ANSI escape code colors in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, ansi-escape

I have a source that has ANSI escape code color attached to the strings it spits out. These strings are being sent to the browser. I want to parse these ANSI escape codes with javascript in the browser so the it looks like it would in a terminal window.

The goal: ANSI strings -> html spans with styling

Is this possible? First I need to know how to parse ANSI strings in JS.

Comment: You have all that rep and can still only muster this as a question? Post some examples of your input strings

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: https://github.com/netzkolchose/node-ansiparser it also works in Browser. But you need to handle the codes it's only a parser, you need to write interpreter with this, check my implementation for jQuery Terminal https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/blob/devel/js/unix_formatting.js

Answer (score 4):

It's been done before.  A quick Google search finds [escapes.js](http://256.io/escapes.js/) as one example.

Comment: What about passing in a string `[32m✎[39m`?

Comment: I want to input ANSI strings and output html span strings that include styling, not files to canvas.